# Static Pages with Shared Ad Contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a Web App developed in Asp.net Core MVC, which produce static HTML pages (to share and load easily) for User Posts. These pages have common area fixed for ads (containing Text + Images).

In Case, I want to change ad content, i have to reproduce all pages with new ad content.

Is there any solution for having such page part referenced to some sort of  page/part, changing by which will change all static pages?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0):

Find Solution by Using iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>You can use the height and width attributes to specify the size of the iframe:</p>

<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```